# visual studio unable to find assert.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm a first year at uni and I just got my new laptop. I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and pulled my solution repo. However, I'm having some issues because it appears that a lot of the files I had on my previous computer were not downloaded in the installation of VS. My university wifi is slow and I don't want to re-download if I don't have to. I followed the previous steps I took to download VS 2017 on my old computer. Yet, I'm getting errors like:

- cannot open source file "assert.h"
- cannot open source file "errno.h"
- cannot open source file "float.h"
- cannot open source file "corecrt.h"
- cannot open source file "stddef.h"
- cannot open source file "stdio.h"

(among 20+ others)

If I right-click and choose the "Open document" on the line with the error, I get the message:
File '_______.h' not found in current source file's directory or in build system path

However, if I go to my include paths, I can find files like:

- cassert.h
- cerrno.h
- ostream.h

but none of the ones that I'm told are missing.

Mainly, I'm wondering if there is a directory with this files I just need to add to the include directory or whether I just need to admit defeat and reinstall.

Thanks for the help, I welcome editing as I'm sure I've messed things up. I'm new to this.

Cheers,

Caleb

Comment: Was the project initially written in `C`?

Comment: Your installation is incomplete, reinstall. Note that some VS versions/variants required separate installation of an SDK.

Comment: You downloaded the Visual Studio *setup package* and not just the files from VS on another computer, right?

Comment: _I can find files like: * cassert.h_ Really? In C, it is usually `assert.h`. In C++, this is wrapped into `cassert` (without suffix). `cassert.h` looks like a strange mix of this. Out of curiosity, I did a `find . -iname "*assert*" -print` in `Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include` and found exactly `assert.h` and `cassert`.

Comment: Yes, something very wrong if you really can see a file called `cassert.h`

Answer (score 10):

Using VS2017 I was able to resolve this same issue by:

1. Right click on solution
2. Selecting 'Retarget Solution'
3. Selecting an SDK from the Windows SDK Version dropdown
4. Clicking OK button

[image]

Comment: I already had the Windows Universal C Runtime installed, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your Visual Studio 2017 installation is probably missing the C packages (they are *not* automatically included with the **Desktop development with C++** workload).

To install it, start the Visual Studio Installer, go to **Individual components**, and check **Windows Universal C Runtime**:

[image]

I think this component is also automatically marked for installation when adding the **Linux development with C++** workload.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by uninstalling my original installation of Visual Studio (2019 version), then reinstalling and including the workload **Desktop Development with C++**.

In contrast to the above solutions, I did not need (and it did not help) to add the Windows Universal C Runtime.

Comment: So we need Windows Kits installed. Thanks