# Can't compile static library with cmake cause compilation `cannot open include file: ...` for any standard header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

Note: I've only tested this problem on windows but that's what I want to solve right now.

I'm trying to create a static library and I'm using CMake to generate the build files. However, building leads to no standard libraries being found. The simplest form I reproduce this issue is with these 3 files:

Test.hpp

```
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
  int DoSomething();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.hpp"

#include <assert.h>

int A::DoSomething()
{
  assert(true);
  return 5;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(MyLib VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "My Lib")

set(SOURCE "src/Test.cpp")

if(WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/std:c++17 /EHsc")
else()
...
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)

add_library(MyLib STATIC ${SOURCE})
```

Running cmake is fine but then running `cmake --build .` I get the following output:
`C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1425~1.286\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -I..\..\..\include /std:c++17 /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\MyLib.dir\src\Test.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\MyLib.dir\MyLib.pdb /FS -c ..\..\..\src\Test.cpp ..\..\..\src\Test.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory`

I'm not sure why it can't find `assert.h`. I'm only using this as an example but this happens with all STL headers. I've also tried using `/MD` `/MT` `/MTd` but it doesn't change anything. Feels like I need to do something special because it's a STATIC library but I couldn't identify what looking around.

Comment: Have you tried to [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27assert.h%27:+No+such+file+or+directory+site:stackoverflow.com) for the error message you got? Have you checked e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325237/visual-studio-unable-to-find-assert-h) and its answers?

Comment: I have tried searching but as I said, I'm using CMake to generate the build files. If I was using visual studio I'd be able to do what the person you linked did. Unfortunately, I'm not using visual studio so I don't have a nice way of checking the libraries linked through it. I also don't have this problem when I'm building an executable. Only when I'm building a static library. So I do have the standard library.

Comment: `cl.exe`, which is used for compile your project, is a compiler for Visual Studio. So Visual Studio settings affects on it.

Comment: Fair enough, however, I checked and I do have the runtime installed as expected and the other answer is not applicable at all. I couldn't find anything else that worked either.

Comment: BTW, **overriding** of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, as you do with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/std:c++17 /EHsc")`, is usually a bad idea: you could loose flags which CMake determines for you. Instead, **append** flags: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17 /EHsc")`.

Comment: That makes sense thanks